# Is it possible to update already sent notification using firebase on ios?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm sending push notification using firebase sdk on backend to the react-native application. We want to achieve that we display only the most recent one notification in notification center. To achieve that on android we can use "tag" property but on iOS seems to be not supported. Is it a way to update message of notification? Or dismiss previous one and replace with new one?

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate if you mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answer. Thank you

Comment: I'm checking right now and I will accept the answer when I finish. But right now I want to say big thank you for quick answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to some constraints. This firebase feature is called collapsible messages . You can read more about it in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages)

Comment: For those who want use it in node js - use function `admin.messaging().send` and as argument object use:  `{
apns: {
      headers: {
        "apns-collapse-id": "event_key"
      }
    },
}`